# Function to return a regex test

Tags: javascript

Good evening, I am not a particularly good programmer.

I want to return the result of the keywordChk function, against a larger set of test keywords. 
However, when I do that, it returns unexpected results due to my lack of skill.

The below works; however, it is somewhat limiting due to hardcoding the phrase into the function.

```
  let arr = [
    /test$/i,
    /foo$/i,
    /bar$/i
  ];

function keywordChk(phrase) {
  for (let tmp of arr) {
  let pattern = new RegExp(tmp);
    if (pattern.test(phrase)) {
      console.log(`true`);
    } else {
      console.log(`false`);
    };
  };
};
keywordChk("foo");
```

When I put the test through a forEach, I get two falses and one true. However, I was expecting everything to be marked as true.

```
   let str = [
    "foo",
    "bar",
    "test"
  ];
  let arr = [
    /test$/i,
    /foo$/i,
    /bar$/i
  ];

function keywordChk(phrase) {
  for (let tmp of arr) {
  let pattern = new RegExp(tmp);
    if (pattern.test(phrase)) {
      return true;
    }
    return phrase;
  };
};
str.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(keywordChk(item));
});
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This code only checks the first element in the loop, then `return phrase` if it doesn't match. Did you mean to move `return phrase` down one line?

Comment: @ggorlen thank you for your warm reception and swift response. Based on your response, I might have two issues? The first, is that I intentionally hardcoded matching strings to test as my regEx array. So in my code example, I expect in console.log 3 true statements. Not 1 true / 2 false or phrase. The second issue is my loop? Perhaps based on your feedback. Apologies, I am not smart enough to modify my code to remedy the original issues, based on your response.

Comment: @ggorlen I just had a go at what you said, and it worked, thank you! You just saved me about a day and more, I may have even given up!

Answer (score 1):

The return statement have to be after the for loop:

```js
let str = ["foo", "bar", "test"];
let arr = [/test$/i, /foo$/i, /bar$/i];

function keywordChk(phrase) {
  for (const regExp of arr) {
    if (regExp.test(phrase)) {
      return true;
    } 
  }
  return phrase; // or return false; 
}

str.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(keywordChk(item));
});
```

Comment: Amazing thank you! Looks like it worked, blimey SO is brilliant.

Comment: You can leave out `let pattern = new RegExp(tmp);` and directly work with `tmp` instead of `pattern` since `tmp` is already a regular expression.

Comment: @cars10m Thank you for vetting my code and offering solutions to condense it. It will help me refine my future scripts. Much appreciated.